# obj-m variable in a kernel module

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

In the kernel module makefile `obj-m` variable exists. Consider the following:

```
CUR = $(shell uname -r) 
DIR = /lib/modules/$(CUR)/build 
PWD = $(shell pwd) 
obj-m   := m1.o m2.o 
default: 
        $(MAKE) -C $(DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

In this `Makefile`, the `default` target contains a recipe which invokes kernel `sub-make`. The `obj-m` variable doesn't get exported to environment thus `sub-make` cannot use it. But if we delete the obj-m variable initialization, then this `make` doesn't compile `m1` and `m2` kernel modules. So, question is:

Why kernel sub-make depends on the non-exported `obj-m` variable in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the make variables are exported to the environment.

`SUBDIRS` gets defined as a make variable.
The kernel makefile looks for the `Makefile` in `SUBDIRS`, reads it, and uses any `obj-*` defined therein.

(According to the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt), you should use `M` instead of `SUBDIRS`.)

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer but can you get a proof-link to the official docs where I can find it?